# Using tensors as indexes in a network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My network has multiple inputs where one of those inputs is an index that is used in the network to index into other tensors.

I am having issues using the tensor as an index.

```
class MemoryLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, memory_size, k, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(kwargs)
    self.memory_size = memory_size
    self.k = k

  def build(self,input_shape):
    # Set up the memory_var

  # Shape of input is [(1,3,6), (1,3)]
  def call(self, input):
    for i in range(3):
      statement = input[0][0,i]
      cluster = input[1][0,i]
      old_sub_mem = self.memory_var[cluster, :-1] #Error here
        
      # Here should be a bunch of stuff I removed because its not relevant

    return tf.expand_dims(self.memory_var, axis=0)
```

I get a `TypeError` saying that `<tf.Tensor 'memory_layer_19/strided_slice_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>` isn't a valid index. I tried calling `.numpy()` on `input[1]` but this doesn't work as the tensor has no shape. From the data I input `cluster` should be a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, input to layers are `tf.float32`. However, to index a tensor, you need integers. You can either cast the inputs of your layer to integers, or you can specify that the input of that layer should be of the integer type.

#### With casting

```
cluster = tf.cast(input[1], dtype=tf.int32)[0,i]
old_sub_mem = self.memory_var[cluster, :-1]
```

#### Specifying the type of the input

I use the functional API in that example:

```
inp_statement = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,6))
inp_cluster = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int32)
memory = MemoryLayer(memory_size=10)([inp1,inp2])
```

---

**Note**: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, but this for loop could probably be optimized out with a call to `tf.gather` or `tf.gather_nd`.